# physics related question

Tags: physics

i am trying to calculate  simple  problem from physic,but i am getting somehow wrong answer.problem is that
 what is a mass of bag which is hold  by child with mass $50$KG,if  there is  force of heaviness on both  which is equal $600$N

so  in shortly,we know that  on child and  bag,there works  $600$N  force of heaviness,we have to find mass of bag.
as i know   force of heaviness on mass on earth is
 $F=m*g$ if we have two mass,then i think formula would  be $F=m_1*m_2*g$ from which $m_2=1.2$,but in book answer is $m_2=10kg$,please help me to clarify why is so?

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be $F=(m_1+m_2)g$?

Comment: aa right yes,i have mixed something,thanks very much

Comment: maybe $F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$? is this homework? or are you doin' this for fun or research?

Comment: no for myself working

Comment: thanks for downvoter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. Take $F=(m_1+m_2)g=(50kg+10kg)9.81\frac{m}{s^2}\approx 600N$.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $(m_1+m_2)g$, where m1+m2 is the total mass, why are you multiplying? But I don't think this is the right place for such a question. I believe physics tag was not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

The mass of child plus bag is $M = m_1+m_2$. So the force for this sum is $F=M\cdot g = 600$N with $g \approx 10 \frac{m}{s^2}$. Since $m_2$ (the mass of the child) is $50$kg:

$$ m_1 = \frac{F}{g}-m_2 = 10 \text{kg} $$